# Transferring large files with Apache NMS

Tags: file-transfer, nms, apache-nms

What is currently considered state-of-art, so to speak, when transferring large files over Apache NMS (using ActiveMQ)? Putting the whole content into a StreamMessage? However, I've seen the naming here is a bit misleading as the file isn't actually streamed over JMS, the entire content will reside in memory (or disk?) and will be sent all at once. Here I got some problems with files > 100 MB: `Apache.NMS.NMSException : Unable to write data to the transport connection: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full`.

`BlobMessage` is not supported in NMS. I really see no option but to split the file in chunks, re-assemble them on the other side, etc.

Comment: You are correct, you need to split the file into manageable pieces, JMS wasn't really designed as a file server.  You can take a look at the ActiveMQInputStream and ActiveMQOutputStream classes in the Java client, you might be able to port that to .NET

Answer (score 0):

how about using  GZIPInputStream,
for example : 
GZIPInputStream inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(gzipped));

Comment: The content is already compressed. And it's C# code (Apache NMS) I'm talking about, which I believe is lacking a lot of functionality when compared to the ActiveMQ Java interface...

Comment: NMS supports compression of Messages natively, just turn the Connection's compression setting on via connection.UseCompression = true;